# LINQ to XML в С#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Есть некий анонимный массив типов:

```
var people = new[]
{
    new {FirstName = "Mandy", Age = 32},
    new {FirstName = "Ilya", Age = 20},
    new {FirstName = "Miwa", Age = 35},
    new {FirstName = "Ura", Age = 15}
};
```

С помощью данных из массива нужно построить *xml* файл. Для этого использую следующий код:

```
XElement peopleDoc = new XElement("People",
   from c in people
   select new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Age", c.Age), new XElement("FirstName", c.FirstName)));
```

Когда элемент `FirstName` вложен в элемент `Person` все норм. А вот когда я хочу сделать что бы элемент `FirstName` был на том же самом уровне с элементом `Person` *LINQ* запрос отказывается видеть свою переменную `c`:

```
XElement peopleDoc = new XElement("People",
   from c in people
   select new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Age", c.Age)), new XElement("FirstName", c.FirstName));
```

Как сделать чтобы `Person` и `FirstName` были на одном уровне?
Хочу чтобы получился вот такой результат:

```
<People>
   <Person Age="32"></Person>
   <FirstName>Mandy</FirstName>  
   <Person Age="20"></Person>
   <FirstName>Ilya</FirstName>  
   <Person Age="35"></Person>
   <FirstName>Miwa</FirstName> 
</People>
```

Comment: У вас второе употребление `c` не относится к селекту.

Comment: Покажите пример результирующего XML, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: @batya, Какой смысл? Если сделать так, как вы предлагаете, то будет нарушена структурная логика.

Comment: @VladD,хм... а Троелсен в книге приводит пример автора и у него он работает. Возможно, опечатка в книге.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну так речь не о примере автора, а о попытке переделать код.

Comment: `XElement peopleDoc =
                new XElement("People",
                    people
                    .SelectMany(c =>
                        new[]
                        {
                            new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Age", c.Age)),
                            new XElement("FirstName", c.FirstName)
                        }));`

Comment: @VladD, я дописал в вопросе нужный результат.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, а через синтаксис запросов можно сделать?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, та я уже все. Сделал.

Comment: @batya: Ну раз сделали, напишите сами ответ, другим будет полезно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, конечно: `XElement peopleDoc2 =
                new XElement("People",
                    from c in people
                    from el in
                        new[]
                        {
                            new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Age", c.Age)),
                            new XElement("FirstName", c.FirstName)
                        }
                    select el)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал не через LINQ запрос, а через метод SelectMany:

```
XElement peopleDoc = new XElement("People", people .SelectMany(c => new[] { new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Age", c.Age)), new XElement("FirstName", c.FirstName) }));
```